# Issue for user operator from managed C++ in C#

Tags: c#, operator-overloading, managed-c++

I am wrapping some C++ code in managed C++ to access it in C#: I can not figure out how to make operators properly work in C#

I create in managed C++:

```
public ref class ClassCLI
{
public:
    double val;
    ClassCLI() {};
    void operator ++() { val++; };
    double% operator[](int i) { return val; }


};
```

This works in managed C++:

```
ClassCLI^ obj = gcnew ClassCLI();
obj++;
obj[0] = 12.0;
```

But in C#, I can not use the operators ++ or [] directly, I have to use some ugly name that defeats the purpose of operators.

```
var obj = new ClassCLI();
obj.op_Increment();
obj.op_Subscript(0) = 12.0;
```

Can one tell me what I am doing wrong ? I says on some posts that operators should be static for C#, it is easy for operator++ but not sure how to do for the operator[]

Comment: Do you get an error when using `obj++` in C#? Which error?

Comment: Yes, obj++ is not available and it won't compile. I read that the operators in C# needed to be static. That is easy for operator++, but I also need the operator[](int i) and it does not seem possible to make this one in static. So still not sure what is the correct way

Answer (score 1):

If you refer to

- [C++/CLI: how to overload an operator to accept reference types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18011634/c-cli-how-to-overload-an-operator-to-accept-reference-types)
- [How to declare the default indexed property in C++/CLI interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27804125/how-to-declare-the-default-indexed-property-in-c-cli-interface)

you can get an idea to implement your `ClassCLI` class.

Sample implementation:

C++

```
public ref class ClassCLI
{
public:
    double val;
    ClassCLI() {};

    property double default[int]
    {
        double get(int index) { return val; }
        void set(int index, double value) { val = value; }
    }

    static ClassCLI^ operator ++(ClassCLI^ c)
    {
        c->val++;
        return c;
    };
};
```

C#:

```
static void Main()
{
   ClassCLI c = new ClassCLI();
   Console.WriteLine(c.val);
   c++;
   Console.WriteLine(c.val);
   c[0] = 12;
   Console.WriteLine(c.val);
   Console.Read();
}
```

Output:

0

1

12